# wrong behavior of messages socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, sockets

I use socket.io and socket.io-client to create chat user - operator. I've made connections, all works good, but message sending has weird behavior.

1. Like I send message from first client to room in socket and don't see it, but other client can
2. When I send second message, the first sent msg just changes for the second one

I see this all messages in my Map on backend(I don't use DB yet) but can't see it on client side.

server

```
app.get("/rooms/:id", (req, res) => {
  const roomId = req.params.id;
  const obj = rooms.has(roomId)
    ? { messages: [...rooms.get(roomId).get("messages").values()] }
    : { messages: [] };
  res.send(obj);
});

app.post("/rooms", (req, res) => {
  const { roomId, name } = req.body;
  if (!rooms.has(roomId)) {
    rooms.set(
      roomId,
      new Map([
        ["users", new Map()],
        ["messages", []],
      ])
    );
  }
  res.json([...rooms.values()]);
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("ROOM:JOIN", ({ roomId, name }) => {
    socket.join(roomId);
    rooms.get(roomId).get("users").set(socket.id, name);
    const users = rooms && [...rooms.get(roomId).get("users").values()];
    socket.to(roomId).emit("ROOM:JOINED", users);
  });

  socket.on("ROOM:NEW_MESSAGE", ({ roomId, name, text }) => {
    const obj = { name, text };
    console.log(rooms.get(roomId).get("messages"));
    rooms.get(roomId).get("messages").push(obj);
    socket.to(roomId).emit("ROOM:NEW_MESSAGE", obj);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    rooms.forEach((value, roomId) => {
      if (value.get("users").delete(socket.id)) {
        const users = [...value.get("users").values()];
        socket.to(roomId).emit("ROOM:JOINED", users);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

client side

```
const [messageValue, setMessageValue] = useState<string>("");
  const [freshData, setFreshData] = useState<Message[]>([]);

  console.log(freshData);

  const onSendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("ROOM:NEW_MESSAGE", {
      roomId: socketData.roomId,
      text: messageValue,
      name: socketData.name,
    });
    setMessageValue("");
  };

  const getFreshData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:4444/rooms/${socketData.roomId}`
    );
    setFreshData(data.messages);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (join) {
      socket.emit("ROOM:JOIN", socketData);
      getFreshData();
      socket.on("ROOM:JOINED", (users) => {
        console.log("new user", users);
      });
    }
  }, [join]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("ROOM:NEW_MESSAGE", (message) =>
      setFreshData([...freshData, message])
    );
    socket.on("ROOM:JOINED", (users) => {
      console.log("new user", users);
    });
  }, []);
```

and just map through all messages, that I should get from server

Where I could make a mistake ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So I had a mistake on client, I need to call socket function in other `useEffect` with dependency `onSendMessage` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("ROOM:NEW_MESSAGE", (message) =>
      setFreshData([...freshData, message])
    );
  }, [onSendMessage]);
```

and to show your sent messages I need to make `onSendMessage` update state with messages like this:

```
 const onSendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("ROOM:NEW_MESSAGE", {
      roomId: socketData.roomId,
      text: messageValue,
      name: socketData.name,
    });
    setFreshData([...freshData, { text: messageValue, name: socketData.name }]);
    setMessageValue("");
  };
```

And it works !